# How to cancel getUserMedia indicator after recording

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio, getusermedia

I'm using the [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and `getUserMedia` to do some audio recording in the browser. When starting the recording, the user is given the "Allow this site to use your microphone" prompt, and once they click allow, Chrome adds an indicator onto the tab's favicon to show that it is recording:

[image: Recording indicator]
<sub>(source: [ubuntuone.com](http://ubuntuone.com/1nBkbmc9vA313WeWtV03Kz))</sub>

My issue is that the indicator never goes away, even after my application has stopped recording. Basically, I'd like to revoke my own recording permissions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you generate a new `MediaStream` object from a `getUserMedia` call, it contains a `MediaStreamTrack` object.

Calling `MediaStream.getAudioTracks()` should return a sequence that represents a snapshot of all the `MediaStreamTrack` objects in the stream with the kind `"audio"`. Same thing applies when calling `MediaStream.getVideoTracks()` to retrieve video track objects.

According to the spec, it looks like you can revoke all given permissions to your app by calling `MediaStreamTrack.stop()` on the audio track object.

Source: [Media Capture and Stream API spec](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#dom-mediastreamtrack-stop)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It also seems like just calling `mediaStream.stop()` works, without getting the tracks.

Comment: Interestingly, though this removes the indicator from the favicon, the recording can actually continue...

Comment: firefox on mac and firefox on windows work different..                 

mediaStream.stop() - worked for windows                       
mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop() - worked for MacOS and ChromeOS

Comment: Since it continues to record, how would I display the indicator again when the user clicks the "Record" button?