# How could I get rid of the recording symbol in chrome or other browsers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio-recording

I am currently using RecordRTC to record an audio from user. It works perfectly fine! Except when the recording has been stopped, chrome seems to continually indicate that my web app is still using the microphone.

http://recordrtc.herokuapp.com/

The above link shows what I meant. After clicking the stop button, then recording indication is still on the browser. How could I get rid of it?

Much thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can remove that indicator after the user gives access to their microphone. Don't think of it as a typical recording indicator that tells you when you're recording. It's more of a security warning to the user, saying "Don't forget you gave permission to this application to use your microphone, because it may be sneakily recording you."

Comment: I have been using the whatsapp web app, and the recording indicator has gone after I finish my recording. :(

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783805/how-to-cancel-getusermedia-indicator-after-recording

Comment: Perhaps we both should have done more research before posting here.